# Unable to Upgrade A Recipe for a Meta-Layer in Yocto Krogoth

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a layer [`meta-canboat`](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/meta-canboat) which has a recipe `canboat_1.0.0.bb` in it.

I am using the `krogoth` version for Yocto.

When I tried using `devtool` in my upgrade workflow as follows:

```
devtool upgrade canboat --version 1.2.0
```

I get the following error:

```
Parsing recipes..done.
NOTE: Fetching canboat...
NOTE: Unpacking...
NOTE: Patching...
NOTE: Unpacking /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/downloads/v1.2.0.tar.gz to /tmp/devtoolXfphO2/
WARNING: Command 'git rebase 04c3c274b585bb2c53ce8cc70930867b091a3c5f' failed:
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Non-root user in Makefile
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       Makefile
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Makefile
Patch failed at 0001 Non-root user in Makefile
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/scripts/devtool", line 342, in <module>
    ret = main()
  File "/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/scripts/devtool", line 329, in main
    ret = args.func(args, config, basepath, workspace)
  File "/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/scripts/lib/devtool/upgrade.py", line 349, in upgrade
    rf = _create_new_recipe(args.version, md5, sha256, args.srcrev, args.srcbranch, config.workspace_path, tinfoil, rd)
  File "/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/scripts/lib/devtool/upgrade.py", line 262, in _create_new_recipe
    fullpath = _rename_recipe_files(origpath, bpn, oldpv, newpv, path)
  File "/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/scripts/lib/devtool/upgrade.py", line 98, in _rename_recipe_files
    return _rename_recipe_file(oldrecipe, bpn, oldpv, newpv, path)
  File "/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/scripts/lib/devtool/upgrade.py", line 91, in _rename_recipe_file
    shutil.move(os.path.join(path, oldrecipe), os.path.join(path, newrecipe))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/workspace/recipes/canboat/canboat_1.0.0.bb'
```

Strange enough the `workspace` directory only the `files/` folder with pre-existing patches already in the layer.

The layer is already added:

```
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/meta  5
meta-poky             /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/meta-poky  5
meta-oe               /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe  6
meta-networking       /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-openembedded/meta-networking  5
meta-python           /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-openembedded/meta-python  7
meta-multimedia       /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia  6
meta-ruby             /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-openembedded/meta-ruby  7
workspace             /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/workspace  99
meta-phytec           /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-phytec  20
meta-qt5              /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-qt5  7
meta-yogurt           /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-yogurt  10
meta-UMG              /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-UMG  6
meta-canboat          /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-canboat  6
meta-influx           /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-influx  6
meta-go               /home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-go  1
```

What is going wrong here? How do I upgrade the recipe if not via `devtool`?

Comment: Does the canboat v1.0.0 recipe build as expected?

Comment: You probably need to recreate your patches based on upstream changes manually?

Comment: It's highly likely that he will need to.

Comment: @danlor should I follow the `devtool modify` workflow here? I am really missing out on what the workflow should be.

Comment: May be it is easier for you to create a canboat_1.2.0.bb instead of upgrading the current one.

Comment: Also, you can try to resolve the merge conflicts if you want (e.g. as you can see, the Makefile of the new version of canboat has been modified and the patch you have for canboat_1.0.0 can't be applied anymore because it doesn't match the actual code).

Comment: @danlor managed to figure it out. The answer was my workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Krogoth Workflow

As mentioned by @danlor and @Nayfe I created a patch for the updated `Makefile` in the Source Tree.

1. I added the source tree repository using:

   ```
   devtool add canboat https://github.com/canboat/canboat.git
   ```

   it should create `workspace/sources/canboat` in the `build` folder
2. I created a patch using the following:

   ```
   # edit the Makefile using your editor (same change as the previous patch)
   git add Makefile
   git commit -m "Add non root user to new Makefile"
   git format-patch -1 -o ../sources/meta-canboat/recipes-support/canboat/files/
   ```
3. In the `sources/meta-canboat` I removed the old `v.1.0.0` recipe and added the new `v1.2.1` recipe and refactored the patch file.
4. Bumped the version to `v1.0.0 -> v1.2.1` and pushed to code to the [`meta-canboat`](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/meta-canboat)